# Button to refresh tab content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple tabs on my homepage..one of them has a button called "refresh" that refreshes only that particular tab. Here's my code:

The external script files:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The tabs structure:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#sm">SM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rm">RM</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab" id="rm">
         //code
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="sm">             
         <button id="refresh">REFRESH!</button>
         //code
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery(which I have included in an external file that I haven't mentioned above):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#refresh', function(){ 
        var x = $(".tabs").tabs("option", "active");        
        $(".tabs").tabs("load", x);
    });
});
```

Whenever I click on the button, I get an error in my console saying :
`Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'`

Please help! I'm very new to this and am unable to solve this problem!

Comment: where about did you insert your "external script files:"? within the head or body ?

Comment: @Os In the head

Comment: @Os, So should I remove the links from the head and shift it to the end of the body?

Comment: try the link @KenH. has posted. that might solve your problem

Comment: Os, I did read that question earlier today...the answer says that we should include `function(){ $("ul.tabs").tabs(); }` in the code..but where exactly??

Answer (score 0):

@KlaraNewbie,

The error is indicating that the tabs have not been initialized.  To initialize add something like the following:

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs();
```

prior to:

```
$('body').on('click', '#refresh', function(){
```

In addition, your HTML structure is incorrect.  Try:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#sm">SM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rm">RM</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab" id="sm">
    a tab
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="rm">
    <button id="refresh">REFRESH!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And change your script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $('body').on('click', '#refresh', function(){ 
        var x = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");        
        $("#tabs").tabs("load", x);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try it though and I am still getting the same error

Comment: @KlaraNewbie works for me but now you're getting a new error. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NppRgg

Comment: @KlaraNewbie, looking more closely at you html, I notice a few problems.  First the nesting of your content should be inside the "tabs" block.  Secondly, I have only see the main tab block use an id to identify the tabs.  Try adding id="tabs" to your first HTML block and modify your script to us the id in the selector instead of a class.  Take a look at the example structures in the documentation [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Comment: @RonMeske, I am unable to understand exactly what I should do...it would be really great if you could show it to me in the form of a code snippet

Comment: @KlaraNewbie, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RonMeske, thank you very much! But now even the tabs that were being listed have vanished

Comment: Take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rmeske/pen/VppKNj)

Comment: Ohkay so i found out that some other jquery was conflicting with this jquery...so the other tabs are back..but the refresh button still isn't working :(

Comment: That is, on clicking the button, the tab is not getting refreshed..I want the tab to refresh in order to fetch the data on tat particular tab once again

Comment: @KlaraNewbie, I focused on providing a solution to the error in your question.  Was that corrected?  As far the refresh button not working take a closer look at the documentation and if you are still having a problem, create a new question that is specific to that issue.

Comment: @epascarello, the question was not a duplicate as the issue was more than just initialization.  The structure of the HTML code was incorrect as well.

Comment: @RonMeske yes , the error is now gone thank you very much! Could you help me with the refresh button not working please? thank you!